# How can I retrieve all transactions for an address using the blockchain API?

Tags: blockchain.info, api, python

Tell me how to interact with https://www.blockchain.com/.
1). I need to withdraw all transactions from the address, my code outputs transactions only for the last day?
2). How do I add additional transaction information (Sigscript, Witness)?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import bitcoin, sys

if len(sys.argv) < 2:
    ADDRESS = "1NDyJtNTjmwk5xPNhjgAMu4HDHigtobu1s"
elif len(sys.argv) < 3:
    ADDRESS = sys.argv[1]
else:
    print('Wallet address must be provided.')

def main():
    #bitcoin.allTransactions(ADDRESS)
    bitcoin.simpleTransactions(ADDRESS)
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the [API documentation](https://www.blockchain.com/api/blockchain_api) specifies, the response of `/rawaddr/$address` will only return up to 50 transactions. There is an optional parameter `&offset=n` which let's you skip the first `n` transactions. The first call, you get fifty transactions. Then you add the parameter `offset=50` to skip the first fifty transactions in the response to the second call. This will result in you retrieving the second fifty transactions (51-100). Increment the offset each time by 50, until you have collected all transactions for the address. Quoting from the documentation:

> **Single Address**
>
> - https://blockchain.info/rawaddr/$bitcoin_address
> - Address can be base58 or hash160
> - Optional limit parameter to show `n` transactions e.g. `&limit=50` (Default: 50, Max: 50)
> - Optional offset parameter to skip the first `n` transactions e.g. `&offset=100` (Page 2 for limit 50)

After you have collected all txids, you look up the details of each transaction with `rawtx/$txid`:

> **Single Transaction**
>
> - https://blockchain.info/rawtx/$tx_hash
> - You can also request the transaction to return in binary form (Hex encoded) using ?format=hex